# Automatic row deletion in SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am developing library management system in ASP.NET. I am using SQL Server 2008 as database. I want to provide book reservation option so that student can reserve book for 15 minutes.

I am storing details of reserve books in the `reserve` table but I want to automatically delete those rows with a reservation time beyond 15 minutes.

Please help me.

Comment: keep a column like "issue_time" and while inserting, put the current timestamp in that column. Run a thread that checks for expired books at regular interval.

Comment: Do you mean a mechanism by which you always show only last 15 mins of resevations?

Comment: If you delete the reservation, how would you know that the book wasn't returned yet?

Comment: if a student(who reserved that book) comes within 15 minutes then its data will move to "issue" table and data from "reserve" table will be delete. If student does not come on time then data from "reserve" table should be delete automatically after 15 minutes so that the book will be reserve by some other student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the option of changing the table structure I would.  Without seeing the overall design I would suggest adding a "Status" column on the reserve table.  The status column could contain on of the known statuses.  Reserved, Pickedup, Returned, Never used.  Create a SQL Agent job that queries the table for "reserved" records, if the create date is older than 15 minutes, change status to "Never Used"  If you really want design it properly, you will want to add a Statuses table, then create a foreign key between the two tables.  If you want to go down the path of the 2 tables and not sure how to do that let me know I can post a SQLFiddle example.